# How to get the adjacent difference of a Vec?

Tags: rust, vector

What's the most idiomatic way to get the Rust `Vec` equivalent of this Python code?

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
a_diff = np.diff(a) # this is the thing I'm trying to emulate in Rust
print(a_diff) # [1 1 1 1]
```

I can figure out multiple unsatisfactory ways of doing this, but I figure there's got to be a clean one-liner approach using `iter()`, right?

```rust
let a: Vec<f64> = (0..5).collect::<Vec<i64>>().iter().map(|x| *x as f64).collect();
let a_diff = ???
```

Comment: You want the difference of each element from the previous one?

Comment: nit: `.collect::<Vec<i64>>().iter()` is redundant in your code. Range syntax is an iterator, so you can just do `(0..5).map(|x| x as f64).collect()`

Answer (score 5):

With stock Rust I'd use `windows`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<f64> = (0..5).map(|x| x as f64).collect();
    let a_diff: Vec<f64> = a
        .windows(2)
        .map(|vs| {
            let [x, y] = vs else { unreachable!() };
            y - x
        })
        .collect();
    dbg!(a_diff);
}
```

(I also removed the needless collection into a `Vec<i64>`.)

When using nightly that can be shortened to this:

```rust
#![feature(array_windows)]
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<f64> = (0..5).map(|x| x as f64).collect();
    let a_diff: Vec<f64> = a.array_windows().map(|[x, y]| y - x).collect();
    dbg!(a_diff);
}
```

Comment: The nightly version is what I had hoped for and is awesome! The approach using `windows` is good for now, though.

Comment: Also, I didn't know about the `dbg!()` macro so woo!

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with `Vec`, you can use [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows):

```rust
let a: Vec<f64> = (0..5).map(|x| x as f64).collect();
let a_diff: Vec<f64> = a.windows(2).map(|s| s[1] - s[0]).collect();
```

If you want to do it using only iterators, you can use [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan), but it's more involved:

```rust
let mut a = (0..5).map(|x| x as f64);
let a_diff: Vec<f64> = if let Some(first) = a.next() {
    a.scan(first, |prev, x| {
        let out = x - *prev;
        *prev = x;
        Some(out)
    }).collect()
} else { vec![] };
```

Or you can use [`tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) from the `itertools` crate:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let a = (0..5).map(|x| x as f64);
let a_diff: Vec<f64> = a.tuple_windows().map(|(a, b)| b - a).collect();
```